# Having the following error on run while query runs perfect in phpmyAdmin

Tags: mysql, visual-studio

I have the following code and I get System.IndexOutOfRangeException: 'Could not find specified column in results: categories.category_id' on execution. What could be the problem.

```
  public List<Category> GetCat()
        {
            try
            {
                List<Category> categories = new List<Category>();
                con.Open();
                

                var cmd = con.CreateCommand();
                cmd.CommandText = "SELECT categories.category_id, categories.category, subcategory.subCatName, subcategory.subCategory_id  from subcategory inner join categories on categories.category_id = subcategory.category_id";

                MySqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();

                while (dr.Read())
                {
                    
                            Category category = new Category(dr.GetInt32("categories.category_id"), dr.GetString("categories.category"), dr.GetInt32("subcategory.subCategory_id"), dr.GetString("subcategory.subCatName"));
                            categories.Add(category);
                    
                }
                return categories;


            }
            catch (Exception)
            {

                throw;
            }
            finally
            {
                this.con.Close();
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error isn't being generate by the SQL, it's from this line;

```
Category category = new Category(dr.GetInt32("categories.category_id"), dr.GetString("categories.category"), dr.GetInt32("subcategory.subCategory_id"), dr.GetString("subcategory.subCatName"));
```

At this point the data is local, and the column names ***do not*** have table prefixes.  So, the error is telling you it can't find those column names.

Try this...

```
Category category = new Category(dr.GetInt32("category_id"), dr.GetString("category"), dr.GetInt32("subCategory_id"), dr.GetString("subCatName"));
```

*(As an aside, if you run the SQL in phpMyAdmin, you'll see the actual column names.)*